# Eclipse Graphiti on RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, graphiti

I have an existing Eclipse RCP application with several views. The idea is to create an application where I can drag and drop objects from one view to another (for instance like Microsoft Visio).

My questions

1. How do I instantiate an empty (grid) canvas with Graphiti on one of my views (if I could) ?
2. Can / Should I still utilize the drag and drop functionality of RCP with Graphiti altogether ?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.